# RTextTools Why does create_analytics throw "Error in order(TOPIC_CODE) create_analytics"

Tags: r, text-classification

I'm having another problem with classifying a virgin dataset with RTextTools and hope someone can shed some light.

I have pre-trained a model (SVM,MAXENT,RF & BAGGING) and term matrix saved for a classifier "C11" with a pretty decent 91%+ ACC & AUC and look fine to me.

The source data for the models looked a bit like...

```
df.SourceData ( label=numeric(0), body=character(0) )
```

Where label was either "1" or "2" (meaning true / false), and body was a string.

The virgin dataset looks like...

```
df.SourceData (code=0, body=character(0) )
```

i.e. every instance in this set has a code (synonymous with label) set to 0 as these are virginal - we don't know the label.  The body is again a text string.

So running the classifier with...

```
## Load pre-built matrix & model
load("original_matrix.RData")     # called doc_matrix
load("original_model.RData")

## Load unknown data set for classifying
df.VirginData <- read.csv(file="VirginData.csv")

## Create NEW document matrix
new_doc_matrix  <- create_matrix(df.VirginData$body,
                                 language="english", 
                                 removeNumbers=v.matrixRemoveNumbers, 
                                 stemWords=v.matrixStemWords, 
                                 toLower=v.matrixToLower, 
                                 removeSparseTerms=v.matrixRemoveSparseTerms,
                                 , originalMatrix=doc_matrix
)

## Add a column to df.VirginData as labels placeholder
df.VirginData$code <- 0 

## Create Container
container <- create_container(new_doc_matrix, df.VirginData$code, testSize=1:3270, virgin=TRUE) # as we have no labels virgin=TRUE 

## Classify Model
results <- classify_models(container,models)

## Create analytics from classified models
analytics <- create_analytics(container, results)
```

This seems to work right up until the point where create_analytics is called.  This falls over with the error in the title (above).  And if I debug step through that function I get right up to line 47 where the issue lays.

```
score_summary <- create_scoreSummary(container, classification_results)

        document_summary <- create_documentSummary(container, score_summary)
        document_summary <- document_summary[,c(2,3,5)]

        raw_summary <- cbind(classification_results, document_summary)

        topic_summary <- create_topicSummary(container, score_summary)
        topic_summary <- as.data.frame(topic_summary[,c(1,3,4)])
        topic_summary <- topic_summary[with(topic_summary, order(TOPIC_CODE)),]
```

**Can anyone shed light on why this might be happening?** - perhaps it is something to do with how I build the new container and in particular the labels bit (df.VirginData$code).  Am I even doing this right for un-labelled docs?

Help appreciated with love.

Comment: Post the full error message.

Comment: Nothing particularly more but here is the whole of what I get...

> func.ClassifyVirginData(100)
[1] "Loading matrix... ./C11-matrix.RData"
[1] "Loading model... C11"
[1] "Creating new document matrix..."
[1] "Classifying models..."
 Show Traceback
 
 Rerun with Debug
 Error in order(TOPIC_CODE) : object 'TOPIC_CODE' not found

Comment: It certainly suggests that you removed the  TOPIC_CODE column with your earlier subsetting operation.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow, which subsetting operation?

Comment: `topic_summary[,c(1,3,4)]`

Comment: right, but that is part of the RTextTools create_analytics function, not mine.   Would some sort of data in issue be causing this to fail?   For example how I am creating the container with a code/label of 0.

Comment: I do not think you have provided enough information to allow a credible answer. Perhaps the package authors should be contacted?

Answer (score 0):

To make create_analytics work, you need to have all of the prediction levels specified in the labels argument of create_container, in your case:

```
df.VirginData$code <- c(0,rep(1,c(nrow(df.VirginData)-1)))
```

These manual codes wont actually matter as long as you have virgin=TRUE in the container argument.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that label summary cannot be properly computed. Since it is virgin data, there is only one label for the new data. What you want, I assume, is the class assignment in document_summary. To fix this problem, I took the parts of the create_analytics function that applied to virgin data, removed a couple lines about topic_summary to force label_summary to be properly produced. You end up with a frequency table for all categories.  Following the else (virgin=TRUE) in create_analytics:

```
score_summary <- create_scoreSummary(container, classification_results)
document_summary <- create_documentSummary(container,score_summary)
document_summary <- document_summary[, c(2, 3, 5)]
raw_summary <- cbind(classification_results, document_summary)
container <- new("analytics_virgin", 
label_summary = data.frame(table(document_summary[,3])), 
document_summary = as.data.frame(raw_summary))
```